# How to find the homoscedastic error term when error variance is product of explanatory variable?

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares

this is a homework question but I want to be sure I have the correct method.

I am given the following model:

$$ Y_i = \beta_1 + \beta_2 X_{2i} + \beta_3 X_{3i} + \beta_4 X_{4i} + \beta_{5i} X_5 + u_i $$

that $\mathbf{E}(u | X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5) = 0$, and that $\mathbf{var}(u | X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5) = \sigma^2 X_2^2$.

Do I divide the entire model through by $\sigma^2 X_2^2$ to obtain the homoscedastic error term?

Any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens to the variance of $u_i$ when you divide it through by any constant $\lambda$?  That will indicate what you want to divide $u_i$ by in order to produce a constant-variance error.

Comment: It becomes $\lambda^2$ correct? So I need to multiply through by $\frac{1}{X_2}$ ?